# Why does my loop break when I input a large int value?

Tags: c++, while-loop, int

Good day all,

I have a simple program I have written and currently testing.
It outputs the smaller of two integer type variables inputted:

```
#include "library/std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() 
{ //PPP by Bjarne Stroustup Chapter 4 drill

    int first, second = 0; 
    cout << "Please type in two numbers seperated by space: ";
    while(cin >> first >> second)
        if(first > second)
            cout << "The smaller value is: " << second << "\nPlease try again: ";
        else
            cout << "The smaller value is: " << first << "\nPlease try again: ";
    return 0; 
}
```

It works fine when inputs are small to medium sized values, but the loop breaks immediately a large value is inputted as one of the variables such as(5678885645684534342646262326245234523).

I'm still new, so it maybe something I'm yet to learn or doing wrong.

Will be grateful if this can be explained.

Comment: Because it's too big to put into an `int`.

Comment: When the conversion to `int` fails, `cin >> first >> second` is not true, so the `while` condition fails and the loop ends.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. Someone tagged this as duplicated and presented the link to the other question asked. It was explained just as you mentioned and a  solution offered. It seems `long` is a new type I didn't know before. I will read up on it.